# How do I change the hostname using Python on a Raspberry Pi

Tags: python

I tried using (going from memory, this may not be 100% accurate):

```
import socket
socket.sethostname("NewHost")
```

I got a permissions error.

How would I approach this entirely from within the Python program?

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to change the hostname permanently, which required making changes in a few places, so I made a shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# /usr/sbin/change_hostname.sh - program to permanently change hostname.  Permissions
# are set so that www-user can `sudo` this specific program.

# args:
# $1 - new hostname, should be a legal hostname

sed -i "s/$HOSTNAME/$1/g" /etc/hosts
echo $1 > /etc/hostname
/etc/init.d/hostname.sh
hostname $1  # this is to update the current hostname without restarting
```

In Python, I ran the script with [subprocess.run](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run):

```
subprocess.run(
    ['sudo', '/usr/sbin/change_hostname.sh', newhostname])
```

This was happening from a webserver which was running as `www-data`, so I allowed it to `sudo` this specific script without a password.  You can skip this step and run the script without `sudo` if you're running as `root` or similar:

```
# /etc.d/sudoers.d/099-www-data-nopasswd-hostname
www-data ALL = (root) NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/change_hostname.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to do change the hostname until the next reboot, many linux system can change it with:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['hostname', 'newhost'])
```

or with less typing but some potential pitfalls:

```
import os
os.system('hostname %s' % 'newhost')
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a different approach

```
    import os
    def setHostname(newhostname):
        with open('/etc/hosts', 'r') as file:
        # read a list of lines into data
        data = file.readlines()

        # the host name is on the 6th line following the IP address
        # so this replaces that line with the new hostname
        data[5] = '127.0.1.1       ' + newhostname

        # save the file temporarily because /etc/hosts is protected
        with open('temp.txt', 'w') as file:
            file.writelines( data )

        # use sudo command to overwrite the protected file
        os.system('sudo mv temp.txt /etc/hosts')

        # repeat process with other file
        with open('/etc/hostname', 'r') as file:
            data = file.readlines()

        data[0] = newhostname

        with open('temp.txt', 'w') as file:
            file.writelines( data )

        os.system('sudo mv temp.txt /etc/hostname')

    #Then call the def
    setHostname('whatever')
```

At the next reboot the hostname will be set to the new name